# I keep trying to enable preview but whenever i upload my java file it says apis are disabled

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I never had this issue before but now whenever i try to upload my class on ed discussions i keep getting this error :
"./assignment2/Caterpillar.java:4: error: SequenceLayout is a preview API and is disabled by default.
import java.lang.foreign.SequenceLayout;
^
(use --enable-preview to enable preview APIs)1"

I've tried the terminal, i've tried project structure,(intellij idea). It is in previewed i have check 10 times already. can someone please advise me on what i should do

Answer (score 0):

`SequenceLayout` is a preview feature introduced in a very recent update of java. You cannot use preview features unless you explicitly elect to enable them. But before you do that: You're clearly following some course or tutorial and there is **zero chance** that's what they meant. 99% odds this is what happened instead: You, or the stuff you received to do this exercise, includes a type that is *also* named `SequenceLayout`, you typed it and allowed intellij to automatically sort out imports for you, and you picked the wrong type to import. Find `import java.lang.foreign.SequenceLayout;` in your code, and delete that line.